# Can't upload large images on server

Tags: php, gd

I'm using GD to resize/upload images.

On my local machine it works fine. Now on my server only small images can be uploaded, anything over 500kb returns a server error 500.

I don't know where to start, I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction as to where to start looking for a solution.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to with GD as it has nothing to do with *uploading* images.  The problem is probably the server's php.ini.  It probably has a `post_max_size` (and/or `upload_max_filesize`) size set too low.

Comment: Some code of how you are trying to upload images would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

check your `php.ini` for `upload_max_filesize`, this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking in your server's php.ini file? If you have access to it then you can change the accepted upload file size.

Example:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 700M
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini file, specifically the settings for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` and set them to the largest size you want the server to accept.